Checking if a polynomial ideal is real
I'm working with a polynomial ideal $I \subset \mathbb{R}[s_1,c_1, \ldots, s_n, c_n]$ generated as $I = \langle s_1^2+c_1^2-1, \ldots, s_n^2+c_n^2-1\rangle$ and looking to show that this ideal is real.
Following Bochnak's Real Algebraic Geometry text, we say that $I$ is real if for any sequence $f_1, \ldots, f_m \in \mathbb{R}[s_1, c_1, \ldots, s_n, c_n]$
$$
\newcommand{\rr}[1]{\smash{{\vphantom{\sqrt{A}}}^{\mathbb{R}}\!\!\!\sqrt{#1}}}
f_1^2 + \cdots + f_m^2 \in I 
\implies f_i \in I \quad\forall i = 1,\ldots, m
$$
Clues I've gathered: Using sage, I've been able to verify that (when working over the rationals):

$I$ is prime for small $n$.
$I$ is radical for small $n$. Given that each $s_i^2+c_i^2-1$ is irreducible, and the generators for $I$ have decoupled influence from the variable pairs $(c_i, s_i)$, I suspect that $I$ is prime and radical, for any $n$. But I haven't been able to show this rigorously, or make headway on the above property about the ideal being real, which is actually what I'd like to show.

Any potential directions would be very appreciated.
My apologies for any imprecision in the above—as an engineer, I'm not coming from a background with formal training in the area. I'm hoping that there is something quick and simple to see here for someone with a more formal background.
Context: Ultimately, I'm looking to check if some other function $g \in \rr{I}$ (the real radical of $I$). By showing the above, we'd have that $I = \rr{I}$, which then allows me to just use a Gröbner basis for $I$ without having to find some algorithm for computing real radicals.

Notation: I made some minor edits to sharpen up your post: (1) \langle s_i^2 + c_i^2 - 1 \rangle give better angle brackets: $\langle s_i^2 + c_i^2 - 1 \rangle$; (2) \implies gives a \Longrightarrow with nice horizontal white space surrounding it; (3) wrapping an inline expression in \smash{} suppresses increased line spacing when ascenders or descenders are too tall; and of course (4) \newcommand can make a macro for complicated but repeated expressions.

The ideal is indeed a real radical ideal. We first observe that it is a radical ideal. This follows from the fact that it is the vanishing ideal of the direct product of $n$ circles. The vanishing ideal of one circle is generated by $s^2+c^2-1$ because this polynomial is irreducible (and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz). The vanishing ideal of a product of affine varieties (inside the product of their ambient affine spaces) is generated by the generators of the factors (in separate variables) - this is a standard fact in algebraic geometry. This shows that your ideal is the vanishing ideal of some variety which implies by the Nullstellensatz that it is a radical ideal. Because the variety is irreducible it is even a prime ideal.
To show that it is a real radical it now suffices to show that the real points of our variety are Zariski dense in the complex points. For an irreducible variety this is the case if and only if it has a smooth real point which can easily be checked for this variety.
